# Silverlight 3 alternative to FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Within a Silverlight 3.0 application I want to use the [AssemblyFileVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.aspx) to display the version information of the application. This is not the same as the [AssemblyVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx) and is typically retrieved in a .NET application using code such as:

```
var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(executingAssembly.Location);
var versionLabel = fileVersionInfo.FileVersion;
```

Unfortunately Silverlight 3.0 runtime does not include the [FileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo_members.aspx) class. Is there an alternative way to access this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to this in a twitter post by [Craig Young](http://twitter.com/craighead) (courtesy of Google's page caching) using [Assembly.GetCustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcustomattributes.aspx) as follows

```
var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var customAttributes = executingAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), false);
if (customAttributes != null)
{
   var assemblyFileVersionAttribute = customAttributes[0] as AssemblyFileVersionAttribute;
   var fileVersionLabel = assemblyFileVersionAttribute.Version;
}
```

Posting this solution for future reference.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to do it with attributes - I'm not sure if it will work in Silverlight though so you'll have to let me know.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
object[] attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), false);
if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
{
    AssemblyFileVersionAttribute fileVersionAttribute = (AssemblyFileVersionAttribute)attributes[0];
    string version = fileVersionAttribute.Version;
}
```

Comment: It does work in Silverlight 3. I already had the answer and was posting if for future reference. My answer attributes the solution to where I found the info first. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Martin, perhaps you could post something to that effect in the question so that people don't waste their time trying to help.

Comment: @overslacked, I will do that next time although to be clear I had the answer lined up and it was only a few minutes from when the question was posted until I posted the answer. Some people are just too quick for me :-)