# Silverlight. Get version of selected file

Tags: c#, silverlight

Can u please me for getting version of selected (through openDialog) file at SilverLight3. 
For other kind app we can user

```
 FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("%systemroot%\\Notepad.exe");
```

But how we can do it at SL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight applications are really intended to run in a [sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)).  As such, many .NET APIs related to accessing files are not included in the Silverlight framework.

If you're looking to get this information about assemblies that are part of your application, you can reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130717/silverlight-3-alternative-to-fileversioninfo-getversioninfo) post, otherwise I don't believe there's a way to do this.