# Getting Assembly File Version for Silverlight Returns an Asterisk

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm trying to get the assembly *file* verison within a Silverlight application. Since Silverlight doesn't have the FileVersionInfo class, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2130746/279516) seems to be the recommended way to get the information:

```
var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var customAttributes = executingAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), false);
if (customAttributes != null)
{
    var assemblyFileVersionAttribute = customAttributes[0] as AssemblyFileVersionAttribute;
    return assemblyFileVersionAttribute.Version;
}
```

However, the above code returns `1.2.0.*`. That is indeed what is in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, but I want the actual file version (without the asterisk) instead of `1.2.0.*`. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want `1.2.0`, `1.2.0.0` or `1.2.0.X` where "X" is the _actual_ version number digit from 0 through 9?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I'm looking for 1.2.0.X where "X" is the actual version number digit from 0 through 9.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297273/getting-runtime-version-of-a-silverlight-assembly

Comment: No, that returns the version instead of the file version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `AssemblyFileVersion` does not auto-increment like `AssemblyVersion` does. The `*` in your *assembly.cs* file is actually part of the AssemblyFileVersion string.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359597/whats-wrong-with-my-visual-studio-auto-incrementing-build-number-syntax) for more.